# C cannot send parameters to function

Tags: c

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   int a = 3;
   int aa = 2;
   int *aaa;
   *aaa = 10;
   func(&a, &aa, aaa);
   printf("%d\n",a);
   printf("%d\n", *aaa);
}
void func(int *b, int *bb, int *bbb){
    *b = *bb;
    //int c = *bbb;
    printf("%d---\n",*b);
    //printf("%d c value \n",bbb);
}
```

I get a segmentation fault while running it

gcc compiler  gcc (GCC) 4.1.2, on linux

Here is the error:

```
>>gcc file.c -o file
file.c:14: warning: conflicting types for ‘func’
file.c:10: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘func’ was here
>>./file
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Which compiler? Which operating system? When you ran the debugger what line of code did it fail on?

Comment: Probably this: `*aaa = 10;` you're trying to use a pointer that doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: `*aaa = 10;` == `Undefined behaviour`!! and `printf("%d\n", *aaa);` == `Undefined behaviour`

Comment: If you couldn't be bothered using `gdb` then you shouldn't be going anywhere near pointers. Bad student! Bad student!

Comment: Hey, what about that warning GCC gave you? Are you just going to ignore it?

Comment: @Kninnug yeah... that failure to forward declare the function prototype... the compiler assumption that `func()` returns `int`... what a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *aaa;
*aaa = 10;
```

You have defined a pointer to integer, but you have not defined any integer which `aaa` can point. At this point `aaa` contains some garbage address, so when you do `*aaa = 10` you are trying to write at that garbage location. As a result you are getting segmentation fault.

To fix this you need to define an integer like this:

```
int aaaValue;
int *aaa = &aaaValue;
*aaa = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is below:-

```
*aaa = 10;
```

`aaa` is a pointer, you can only perform the above after allocating memory to `aaa` like:

```
aaa = malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
```

Comment: Or, for example, `aaa = &aa;` to make them point to the same thing.

Comment: @Kninnug: Yes, that is also a possibility.

Comment: Don't forget to `free` if you do `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

int *aaa; is not initialised i.e aaa is pointing to some garbage address (may be out of your programe segment) and you are modifying this adders   *aaa = 10;

Don't you need forward ddeclaration to compile this code?